# How to pass json directory to the template within the django framework?

Tags: json, django, d3.js, django-templates, directory

I am new to D3 and django and I hope to combine them for visualization. I download one [code example of D3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045), and it needs the json file as data source.
I then write a template in Django like:
`

```
.link {
stroke: #ccc;
}

.node text {
pointer-events: none;
font: 10px sans-serif;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 1500,
    height = 2000

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
              .gravity(.05)
              .distance(100)
              .charge(-100)
              .size([width, height]);


d3.json("{{file}}", function(error, json) {
//d3.json("all_0.0007_0.15.json", function(error, json) {
force
  .nodes(json.nodes)
  .links(json.links)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
               .data(json.links)
               .enter().append("line")
               .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.color); })
               .attr("class", "link");


var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(json.nodes)
              .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .call(force.drag);
     //.on('dblclick', connectedNodes); //Added code 

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.degree;})
    .style("fill", function (d) {return color(d.group);})

node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 3)           //It means the offset of label and circle
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name })
    .style("font-size",function(d) { return d.degree*2+'px' })
    .style("stroke", "gray");  



force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  });
});

</script>`
```

I try to pass the directory in my computer to {{file}} in the template. But it seems that the browser can not find the json file even the template is in the same folder with json file.
Anyone can tell me how to pass the directory of json file in my local computer to the template? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you passing in a http:// URL or a file:/// URL?  file:/// won't work in most browsers, try passing in a http:// URL.  You'll probably need for django to treat it like a static file, so put it in the folder that STATIC_URL points to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, file:/// cannot work. But when I use the built-in server in python like "http://localhost:8888/" and use that directory list, the firefox deny it again as 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8888/all_0.0007_0.15.json. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.' How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't serve up static pages that way.

Because every request that goes to the Django server (in your case `http:localhost:8888`) gets routed through Django's URL Dispatcher (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/), you need to setup Django url routes to handle EVERY url you might want, otherwise Django will just 404 the request.

In order to serve static files you will need to setup Django to serve static content (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/).